# Why are these expressions indeterminate expressions?

Tags: infinity

Why are these  $1^\infty,$ $0\cdot\infty$ and $\infty^0$ indeterminate forms. Why we can't solve these expressions?

Comment: They are mnemonic formulas to remember the cases in which the formulas that describe how the limit operation behaves with respect to the arithmetic operations, do not work.

Comment: Let us only look to $0\cdot \infty$. The formula that it is referring to is $\lim f(x)g(g)=\lim f(x)\lim g(x)$. But the formula only works under certain restrictions. One of them is if $\lim f(x)=0$ and $\lim g(x)=\infty$.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is because one can find examples: $f(x)=1/x$, $g(x)=x^k$. In which $\lim f(x)g(x)$ depends in what the functions $f$ and $g$ actually are, and not only on $\lim f(x)$, and $\lim g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you buy that $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and $\frac{0}{0}$ are indeterminate?  If so, it's easy to see why those are indeterminate:

\begin{align}
0\cdot\infty =& \frac{1}{\infty} \cdot \infty = \frac{\infty}{\infty} \\
0\cdot\infty =& 0 \cdot \frac{1}{0} = \frac{0}{0} \\
1^\infty =& e^{\ln(1)\cdot\infty} = e^{0\cdot\infty}\text{, the exponent is indeterminate} \\
\infty^0 =& e^{\ln(\infty)\cdot0} = e^{\infty\cdot0}\text{, again, the exponent is indeterminate}
\end{align}

Here is a way to informally see why they would be indeterminate.  You have to remember that these are really limits.  So we don't actually plug in $0$ and $\infty$.

1. 1. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}0\cdot x = 0$
   2. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}x\cdot \infty = ?$ What is it approaching? At every point $x > 0$ this is infinite and at every point $x < 0$ it's $-\infty$.  So which is it? $0$ or $\pm\infty$?  It's indeterminate and it could be none of those.
2. 1. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} 1^x = 1$
   2. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}x^\infty = ?$.  Again, when $x > 1$ this is infinite and when $x < 1$ (but very close to $1$, so still positive) this is $0$.  Again, so which is it? $0$, $1$, or $\infty$?  It's indeterminate and, again, could be none of those.
3. 1. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^0 = 1$
   2. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\infty^x = ?$.  Now when $x > 0$ this is infinite, when $x < 0$ this is $0$.  So, for the last time, which is it, $1$, $0$, or $\infty$--it's indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have cohesion if you accept a certain value for $0\cdot\infty$.

For example consider the expression $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{k}{x}\cdot x= k$.

As you can see it depends on the value k. Similar arguments can be made for the other indeterminate forms you pose.